# Multiple search items in iOS search field

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am not sure if this exists or if its possible by default in iOS, but this is just a doubt which I have got. I would like to know if its even possible to search for multiple items in an iOS search field. If yes, it is okay and common to do so? I haven't seen too many apps which allows me to do so.

I know it might be possible if I override the search method to an extent but I did like to know if theres a better and elegant solution.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "search for multiple items"? You can easily search and have a multiple item result in a tableview...

Comment: You can easily do this but you need to implement `searchBar:textDidChange:` or one of the UISearchDisplayController delegates (i.e. searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch) to get the text. Once you have the text, you can break down the text and use whatever kind of comparison or even SQL command you want to do the search.

Comment: What i meant by multiple items is search for multiple items in the search bar. For eg, search for more than one name etc, etc. Exactly like what the split wise app pay bill search bar does.